# Transparent Background in QWebEnginePage

Tags: c++, qt, transparent, qt5.4, qtwebengine

We are trying to port some application from Qt 4 to Qt 5.4. The Qt 5.4 has a new web engine. We used to make the background of `QWebView` and `QWebPage` to be transparent:

```
view = new QWebView(this);
QPalette palette = view->palette();
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Base, Qt::transparent);
view->page()->setPalette(palette);
view->setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent, false);
```

But this code doesn't work for `QWebEngineView` and `QWebEnginePage`. The point is that `QWebEnginePage` doesn't have such an API like `setPalette`.

Can anyone find a way to solve this?

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41960, this is now working by simply using this line:

```
webEngineView->page()->setBackgroundColor(Qt::transparent);
```

I've tried it in Qt 5.6 and it works well.

**Update**: In order to make this answer more helpful, let me show all relevant code.

In MainWindow, I have set this:

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
setAutoFillBackground(true);
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

For the `webEngineView` object, I have set these attributes:

```
webEngineView->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
webEngineView->setStyleSheet("background:transparent");
webEnginePage = webEngineView->page();
// https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41960
webEnginePage->setBackgroundColor(Qt::transparent);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work at all. When I use this code in a webEngineView that is inside a transparent window (to display on top of another window), the background of a website that contains nothing but a div with text remains white. Tested with Qt 5.7.  Using a different widget with a QGraphicsOpacityEffect on it works, so transparency does work... just not with a QWebEngineView, it seems.

Comment: After fiddling around a bit more, it seems that the background of the PAGE does become invisible indeed. So I guess it does work. However, the background of the QWebEngineVIEW remains white so it isn't really helping much.

Comment: In your HTML, did you use transparent background in your CSS? like this: body {
    background: transparent;
} otherwise, I think by default the HTML would have a white background.

Comment: Yes, of course. I did that, and as I said the color is actually applied. But there is always white behind it. And there is nothing behind the QWebEngineView on the Qt side that could be white, so it must be the view. A gave up on that by now and am doing the rendering of the browser site myself.

Comment: In the MainWindow, I have this:     setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    setAutoFillBackground(true);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint); For view, I have these:     webEngineView->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    webEngineView->setStyleSheet("background:transparent");
    webEnginePage = webEngineView->page();
    // https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41960
    webEnginePage->setBackgroundColor(Qt::transparent);
I hope it helps, I haven't tested against Qt5.7, but I think it should work in similar way.

Comment: @TheSHEEEP I also updated the answer with better format for code.

Comment: Very interesting. I had definitely tried out these exact settings, too, but it did not work. Now it did, though. The difference was that I set Qt::transparent AFTER the page was loaded, while you set it before loading the page. That seems to make all the difference (I can reproduce that behavior). Seemingly, Qt uses that setting to construct the page background, but won't touch it again if changed afterwards.

Comment: To end this discussion: I reported this as a bug on Qt: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59216

Answer (score 0):

No. A partial solution has been committed to upstream, but it covers only QtQuick and you can't have any elements on top:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41960