# QT QWebEngineView transparency for transparent html elements?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I am trying to display some html in PyQT5 with QWebEngine. The problem is that the background (body) of the html is set to 'transparent', but QT won't display it as transparent.

I have been able to make the window frameless, and have been able to make the white part around the html that QT adds transparent, but no where on the internet can I find a way to have QT correctly render the transparent body background as actually transparent (instead of white).

If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it!

```py
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebChannel import QWebChannel

my_html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
    body {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    #square {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="square"></div>
</body>
</html>
"""


class Browser(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):

    def __init__(self, html):
        super().__init__()

        self.url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.getcwd() + os.path.sep)
        self.page().setHtml(html, baseUrl=self.url)


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, html):
        super().__init__()
        self.html = html

        self.init_widgets()
        self.init_layout()
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)

        # these make the border QT adds transparent, and removes the title bar
        # but doesn't affect the body background of the html which is set to transparent
        self.setStyleSheet("background: transparent; border: transparent;")
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)  # don't know what this does, as far as I know, nothing

    def init_widgets(self):
        self.browser = Browser(self.html)

    def init_layout(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)


def start():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window(my_html)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

[Picture for the result of the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exBRl.jpg)

Comment: maybe it need to set transparency for `<html>`  or for `central_widget` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer in old question for Qt and C/C++:
[Transparent Background in QWebEnginePage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183738/transparent-background-in-qwebenginepage)

`page` has default background `white` and you have to change it

```py
page = self.page()

page.setBackgroundColor(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

page.setHtml(html, baseUrl=self.url)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! I couldn't quite translate the C/C++ code to python myself.